# Disable automatic regenerating features in abaqus

Tags: python, abaqus

I have more than 2000 elements in `abaqus` assembly file. Each time I run from Python file, it regenerates features while adding an assembly. This takes quite long time during assembly process even in 'Part' module

[image]

as shown in picture.

How to disable automatic regenerating features during assembly, so that I could regenerate features only after completion of assembly by clicking 'Feature' - 'Regenerate'?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you must be using `regenerate()` method and hence, it is regenerating the assembly. Just avoid using it in your code.

Alternatively, in the Abaqus/CAE GUI, you can do it as shown below.

[[image]]